# Xpath: first preceding and following sibling

Tags: xml, xpath

XML:

```
<body>
    <h2><font style="font-weight: bold">Baz</font></h2>
    <p><img title="image" /></p>
    <p>Baz 0 with an <a href="http://">anchor</a> element.</p>
    <p>Baz 1 with an <a href="http://">anchor</a> element.</p>
    <hr />
    <h2><font style="font-weight: bold">People</font></h2>
    <ul>
        <li>People 0 with <a href="http://" >an anchor</a> element.</li>
        <li>People 1 with an <a href="http://" >an anchor</a> element.</li>
    </ul>
    <hr/>
    <h2><font style="font-weight: bold">Sales</font></h2>
    <ul>
        <li>List item 2 with an <a href="http://" >an anchor</a> element.</li>
        <li>List item 3 with an <a href="http://" >an anchor</a> element.</li>
        <li>List item 4 without an anchor element.</li>
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <h2><font style="font-weight: bold">Sales</font></h2>
    <p><img title="image" /></p>
    <p>sales 0 with an <a href="http://">anchor</a> element.</p>
    <p>sales 1 with an <a href="http://">anchor</a> element.</p>
    <hr />
    <h2><font style="font-weight: bold">Foo</font></h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Foo 0 with <a href="http://" >an anchor</a> element.</li>
        <li>Foo 1 with an <a href="http://" >an anchor</a> element.</li>
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <h2><font style="font-weight: bold">Bar</font></h2>
    <p><img title="image" /></p>
    <p>bar 0 with an <a href="http://">anchor</a> element.</p>
    <p>bar 1 with an <a href="http://">anchor</a> element.</p>
    <hr />
</body>
```

This xpath: `//p[a and preceding-sibling::h2[font[text()='Sales']][1] and following-sibling::hr[1]]`

Returns:

```
<p>sales 0 with an <a href="http://">anchor</a> element.</p>
<p>sales 1 with an <a href="http://">anchor</a> element.</p>
<p>bar 0 with an <a href="http://">anchor</a> element.</p>
<p>bar 1 with an <a href="http://">anchor</a> element.</p>
```

Desired `p`:

```
<p>sales 0 with an <a href="http://">anchor</a> element.</p>
<p>sales 1 with an <a href="http://">anchor</a> element.</p>
```

Desired `li`:

```
<li>List item 2 with an <a href="http://" >an anchor</a> element.</li>
<li>List item 3 with an <a href="http://" >an anchor</a> element.</li>
```

What am I missing?

How would I alter the xpath to include `li/[a]` in the same manner that I'm including `p/[a]`?  The `preceding/following-sibling` wouldn't work with `li`.

Comment: Can you please add an example of what you mean in your last paragraph (about the `li`)? What should be selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just need to specify that it's the first preceding-sibling h2:

```
preceding-sibling::h2[1]
```

updated xpath (I also simplified the test of `Sales`):

```
//p[a and preceding-sibling::h2[1][.='Sales'] and following-sibling::hr]
```

Also, if you need to be certain that the first following-sibling that isn't `p` is `hr`, you can try this...

```
//p[a and preceding-sibling::h2[1][.='Sales'] and following-sibling::*[not(self::p)][1][self::hr]]
```

If you're trying to also select `li` in addition to `p`, you *could* update the xpath to use `preceding::` and `following::`, but you'd have to account for any elements that might appear as children of `p` like `a`, `span`, etc...

```
//*[self::p or self::li][a and preceding::h2[1][.='Sales'] and following::*[not(self::p) and not(self::li) and not(self::a)][1][self::hr]]
```

This would select the following from your sample XML...

```
<li>List item 2 with an <a href="http://" >an anchor</a> element.</li>
<li>List item 3 with an <a href="http://" >an anchor</a> element.</li>
<p>sales 0 with an <a href="http://">anchor</a> element.</p>
<p>sales 1 with an <a href="http://">anchor</a> element.</p>
```

However, I'd recommend a second xpath to target `li` specifically...

```
//li[a and preceding::h2[1][.='Sales'] and ../following-sibling::*[1][self::hr]]
```

Comment: Will you explain the `../following-sibling::*[1][self::hr]]` syntax a bit?

Comment: @craig - Sure, the `..` goes up to the parent element. The `following-sibling::*[1]` is the first following sibling element. The `[self::hr]` tests to see if that element is an `hr`.